# Logcat output of my app vanished from logcat output

Tags: android, logcat

i have a problem with logcat output of my app: 

Normally logging to logcat works. But at some times my app's output seems to be entirely removed from the logcat output. Though i can prove that the app logged, there is not a single line in logcat.

When does this happen:

I shedule my app to wakeup at midnight by a BroadcastReceiver starting a Service. The app wakes up and creates a logfile, writes to that file and to logcat in parallel by calling a function which writes to both. The logfile contains 3 lines written. (and then the app somehow dies.) At least these 3 lines have been also logged to logcat.

Next day i display all logcat messages, which encloses midnight. Not a single line logged for my app.

I think Android has purged my App from memory and at midnight it is loaded again (and crashes because it is not initialized properly). But why is there no logcat output?

thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logcat has a size limit.  Once this limit is reached, older messages are purged to make room for the new ones coming in.  It's not that Logcat is removing your app's messages specifically, it's that in the course of running over night there are so many other messages going to Logcat that yours are being removed.

To see the buffer size on your specific device, plug it in and execute the following command in a shell window:

```
adb logcat -g
```

If you need to collect log messages at a time where you can't physically be looking at the output window, you're doing the right thing by logging to a file.  I do something similar where I'll set a global flag on the build that tells it whether to log normally or output to a local file on my phone.

Comment: i see there are actually two buffers, one for system and one for _me_. Though _my_ buffer is larger, the system buffer reached farther back in time...<br>Thanks for your answer!